# Reusable Select Form Component Undefined Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, reusability

I have a reuseable component i created and the value is undefined. I console logged the currentTarget in the Select.tsx and it returns the value correctly. However, the actual component using the select is the one that returns an undefined value. What am i missing here?

**This is the code in the select.Tsx**

```
export const Select = (props: any) => {
    const [data] = useState(props.data);
    const [selectedData, updateSelectedData] = useState('');

    function handleChange(event: any) {
        updateSelectedData(event.currentTarget.value);
        console.log(event.currentTarget.value, 'in select.tsx line 10');
        if (props.onSelectChange) props.onSelectChange(selectedData);
    }

    let options = data.map((data: any) => (
        <option key={data.id} value={data.id}>
            {data.label}
        </option>
    ));

return (
    <>      
     <select
       className={props.className ? props.className : 'float-right rounded-lg w-[50%] '}
       onChange={handleChange}>

      <option>Select Item</option>
     {options}
      </select>
    </>
  );
};
```

**This is the code being used in the actual component...**

```
...
const actionSelectOptions = [
   { id: 1, label: 'Pricing Revised', value: 'Pricing Revised' },
   { id: 2, label: 'Cost Build-up Posted', value: 'Cost Build-up Posted' },
   { id: 3, label: 'Pricing Created', value: 'Pricing Created' },
 ];

function onSelectChange(event: any) {
   console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
 }

return (
...

<Select
className="flex justify-center items-center rounded-lg"
data={actionSelectOptions}
onSelectChange={onSelectChange}
/>
...                                         
)
```

I tried changing between target and currenTarget in the main component. It both get undefined.. the console works in the select component it seems as if the data is not passing on as its suppose to.
I also tried writing an arrow function within the actual called component for example:

```
<Select
...

onSelectChange={(e)=> console.log(event.currentTarget)}
```

Comment: Possible solution: I just tried using bind.. I don't fully understand bind. but when I updated my select element like this: 
`<Select
...
onSelectChange={(event: any) => onSelectChange.bind(event)} 
/>
`
My console no longer gives me an error that its undefined... Is this a good solution? Can anyone chime in? The only possible issue is that the console prints the log from the select.tsx not the console.log in the actual main component function.